# NGINX to pass digest authorization to Apache

Tags: apache, nginx, digest

I have a NGINX in front of Apache which has both Basic and Digest authentication turned on. I'd like a set up where a user connects to NGINX (using Basic or Digest) and NGINX simply proxy the request to the Apache where the actual authentication happens. I have the Basic case working but not the Digest. Here's how the config for Basic looks like:

```
location /basic {
      proxy_set_header x-user $http_x_user;                
      proxy_pass       http://my.apache.server; // where authentication happens
  proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
      proxy_set_header       Host $host;
      proxy_set_header       X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

}

Could somebody help me out on how to accomplish the Digest case?

Comment: I would let nginx handle basic auth and proxy_pass digest auth to apache.

Comment: @Cole Could you give me concrete config eg.? Tried the following but it didn't work.

location /digest {
               proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass_request_headers on;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwared-User  $http_authorization;
                proxy_set_header       Authorization $http_authorization;
                proxy_pass_header  Authorization;
                proxy_pass       http://apache.server.com;

        }

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample from a config that worked for me:

```
location /basic {  # let nginx handle basic auth
    auth_basic  "Basic Authentication";
    auth_basic_user_file    conf/htpasswd;
}

location /digest {  # pass digest auth to another server
    proxy_pass  http://my.apache.server;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that (and tried again just now) and didn't work. I get a 400 (Bad request) back. Any ideas? I do appreciate your help.

Comment: In my case, I passed digest authentication to [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net). What happens if you comment out the proxy_set_header directives?

Comment: I'll try that when I get home and will let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work. Bleh! I can hit the apache using a rest client with digest checked, and i get a success back. So, i am stumped why it wouldn't via the nginx. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you got the solution? I am facing similar issue and answer would be helpful.